# Listview Image databinding change attribute from jquery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone please help me with my difficulties as how to change image src attribute from listview databinding using jQuery. I'd like it, when the user click the img from listview databind change the `<img id="imgviewer" src="" />`  tried this:

```
$('img').click(function() {            
            $("#imgviewer").attr('src', 'uploadsimg/' + $('this').attr('title'));
        });
```

but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

here's my asp code

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSubAlbumDB" ItemPlaceholderID="subitemContainer" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="photolist">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="subitemContainer" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="" title="<%# Eval("Filename")%>">
                <img border="0" src="uploadsimg/thumbnail/<%# Eval("Filename")%>" title="<%# Eval("Filename")%>" alt="" height="35" width="50" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `this`.

```
$('img').click(function() {            
    $("#imgviewer").attr('src', 'uploadsimg/' + $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. it takes ages for me to post this question as I'm newly registered and saying i cannot post images blhahh... blahh... to this site and with just one reply from you solve my problem, I didn't realize that quotes around this.

Comment: @Flex, good to hear that :). You should accept an answer if it solves your problem.